# Is there an algorithm like std::max_element for the second largest element?

Tags: c++, algorithm, max, std

The standard library provides `std::max_element` to find the largest element in an iterable, e.g.:

```
std::vector<float>::const_iterator max = 
  std::max_element(obj.pt()->begin(), obj.pt()->end());
return std::distance(obj.pt()->begin(), max);
```

Is there also something to get an iterator for the n-th largest element?

(Note that `max_element` returns an iterator and this is actually important: Rather than for the value itself, I am looking for the position of the n-th largest element within the iterable.)

Comment: `std::nth_element`, although it is modifying the sequence.

Comment: @dyp any difference to use `std::sort` ?

Comment: It must not modify the sequence.

Comment: @lcjury, `std::nth_element` is O(n) instead of O(n log n).

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig, If you don't mind O(n) space, you can create a copy and keep linear time. Unfortunately, that does mean another potentially big allocation for the copy.

Comment: If you can create a copy use `std::max_element` twice after remove the first max_element only if there are no duplicates

Comment: Are you really interested in the nth element, or specifically in the second largest element? To get the second largest element efficiently, you can use `std::accumulate` with a custom binary operator (and some inelegant error checking).

Comment: Indeed, at the moment I am mostly interested in the 2nd largest (I was assuming that most solutions would be general, so I asked for the general case). You seem to have a certain solution in mind, so you should probably make an answer out of that.

Answer (score 6):

max_element() method can be used to get second largest element by passing lambda function which compares the element with the previously found largest element and if it is equal to the largest element then it'll simply skip that element.

```
    auto largest = max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    auto secondLargest = max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                                     [&largest](unsigned long &a, unsigned long &b) {
                                         if (a == *largest) return true;
                                         if (b == *largest) return false;                                         
                                         return a < b;
                                     });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are specifically interested in the second-largest element, you can do a simple scan of the array in which most elements require a single comparison:

```
float second_largest_element(std::vector<float> vec) {
  float m2, m1;
  /* Check to make sure that vec has at least 2 elements!! */
  std::tie(m2, m1) = std::minmax(vec[0], vec[1]);
  for (auto it = vec.begin() + 2, limit = vec.end();
       it != limit;
       ++it)
    if (*it > m2) std::tie(m2, m1) = std::minmax(*it, m1);
  return m2;
}
```

Getting the index of (or an iterator to) the second largest element is very similar, although `std::minmax` is less useful. Here's a very sloppy example:

```
template<typename T>
typename T::iterator second_largest(T& container) {
  using iterator = typename T::iterator;
  iterator limit = container.end();
  iterator it = container.begin();
  if (it != limit) {
    iterator first = it++;
    if (it != limit) {
      iterator second = it++;
      if (*first < *second) std::swap(first, second);
      for (; it != limit; ++it) {
        if (*second < *it) {
          if (*first < *it) { second = first; first = it; }
          else              { second = it; }
        }
      }
      return second;
    }
    return first;
  }
  return it;
}
```

You could also consider using `std::accumulate` to scan the array, although the explicit for loop is not complicated.

Answer (score 2):

As Dyp mentioned in comment, if you are fine to alter the order of elements within your `vector` you can use `std::nth_element` as follows. On top if you use `find` again over `vector` you will get original position of the nth element from `vector`. Since `nth_element` modifies the positions, you have to keep a local copy of it before doing `nth_element` operation over vector.

2nd largest element:

```
std::vector<float> vf{1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f};
std::vector<float> orig_vec = vf;

std::nth_element(vf.begin(), vf.begin()+1, vf.end(), std::greater<float>{});
float second = *(vf.begin()+1);
auto it = std::find(orig_vec.begin(), orig_vec.end(), second);
```

nth largest element:

```
std::nth_element(vf.begin(), vf.begin()+n-1, vf.end(), std::greater<float>{});
float nth = *(vf.begin()+n-1);
auto it = std::find(orig_vec.begin(), orig_vec.end(), nth)
```

Comment: But that wouldn't allow me to obtain the *position* of the nth element in the original vector, right?

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig I edited the answer to get nth position from original `vector`

Comment: I have one objection: nth_element doesn't return a value ( or anything at all really ) according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element), so you really need to copy the vector first.

Comment: @Paul Your red flag is right and I corrected the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Mutating

You can use [`std::rangs::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/nth_element) if you are allowed to modify the original vector:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v{4, 2, 1, 3};

// C++20
std::ranges::nth_element(v, v.begin() + 1, std::ranges::greater{});
// C++11
std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin() + 1, v.end(), std::greater<int>{});

std::cout << "Second greatest: " << v[1];
```

### Non-mutating

If you are not allowed to modify the original, you can create an extra buffer and use [`std::ranges::partial_sort_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/partial_sort_copy):

```cpp
const std::vector<int> v{4, 2, 1, 3};
std::array<int, 2> buffer{};

// C++20
std::ranges::partial_sort_copy(v, buffer, std::ranges::greater{});
// C++11
std::partial_sort_copy(v.begin(), v.end(), buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), std::greater<int>{});

std::cout << "Second greatest: " << buffer[1];
```

#### Position within the original

In either case, you don't obtain the position of the element in the *original* vector.
To do that, you would have to create a `std::vector<std::size_t>` of indices and sort that instead.

```cpp
const std::vector<int> v{4, 2, 1, 3};
// The following is a C++23 way to do = {0, 1, 2, 3}.
// There are obviously ways to do that prior to C++23 too, e.g. with std::iota.
std::vector<std::size_t> indices(std::from_range, std::views::iota(0, v.size());

// C++20
std::ranges::nth_element(
    indices, indices.begin() + 1,       // input range and nth
    std::ranges::greater{},             // comparison
    [&v](std::size_t i) { return v[i]; } // projection
);
// C++11
std::nth_element(
    indices.begin(), indices.begin() + 1, indices.end(),
    [&v](std::size_t i, std::size_t j) {
        return v[i] > v[j];
    }
);

// Second greatest element is located at index indices[1]
std::cout << "Second greatest: " << v[indices[1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial algorithm to implement in linear time. The naive approach would be to compare the first two values, and select them as the max and second largest values.  Then you need to iterate over the other elements comparing each new element with both of them and adjusting your current max and second largest values.  For most use cases that is probably more than enough.  If you really care about performance (as in you care *a lot*) you will need to think what values you want to compare to minimize the number of comparisons.

Also note that `float` (floating point in general) have quirks... you might get funny values if your input contains NaN or infinite values.

Comment: I updated the question, but your answer is still valid.

Answer (score -1):

It took me a while to find a solution, because I worked with const vector (so I can't use nth_element) and copy would be just wasting (especially, when vector is holding a bigger structures). So I came with this:

```
// Find 1st max
auto max1 = max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
if (max1 != vec.end())
    // Use max1

// Find 2nd max. Split the vector into 2 parts, find max and merge results
auto max2Beg = max_element(vec.begin(), max1);
auto max2End = max_element(max1 + 1, vec.end());
auto max2 = max2Beg == max1 ? max2End :
            max2End == vec.end() ? max2Beg : max(max2Beg, max2End);
if (max2 != max1 && max2 != vec.end())
    // Use max2
```

Comment: One important thing: You will need to define predicate for `max_element()` for example `auto predicateRef = [](const auto& lhcs, const auto& rhcs) { return lhcs.getValue() < rhcs.getValue(); }` and another one for `max()` `auto predicatePtr = [](const auto* lhcs, const auto* rhcs) { return lhcs->getValue() < rhcs->getValue(); }`.